# DLL Works in MFC App But No In .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mfc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MFC Dll with COM Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719968/mfc-dll-with-com-interface)

I have an old DLL which was written in VC6. I am trying to get this to work with a .NET Winforms application. I have imported the DLL and call the function in it. This works, I can break on the DLL see that everything is passed correctly to it but later the DLL fails when trying to create a COM component with CoCreateInstance. This errors with a access violation. The same DLL used in a MFC app with the same parameters passed to it works fine.

Any ideas as to why this fails in .NET but not in MFC?

Answer (score 0):

The COM component probably needs single-threaded apartment (STA), while your .Net thread is in a multi-threaded apartment (MTA). Try to call your DLL only from a specific STA thread.

Comment: How do I ensure this in .NET?

Comment: I have now called the DLL from its own thread. I set this thread to STA by calling SetApartmentState before I call Start. However, it doesn't make any difference.